# error typeerror rxjs_observable__webpack_imported_module_1__.observable.of is not a function

Tags: angular, observable, nativescript

This is my project https://github.com/bestazad/confusion and when I search `observable` inside my project, I see I have imported it with this line of code `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` in all the files that I needed.

And it seems there is no error in my project. But when I run the project inside the Android emulator I see this error message in the emulator's screen:

> error typeerror
>   rxjs_observable__webpack_imported_module_1__.observable.of is not a
>   function

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check for the reference of `Observable.of`, it was syntax used with 5.x version of the library. Since v6.x the syntax has changed, you will import each operator from `rxjs/operators`. Checkout this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9fdpGthrXA) for quick steps on migration.

Comment: I don't have `observable.of` module but had `throw` module that I changed it to `throwError`, also `Observable.throw` to just `throwError` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply import like this. This is rxjs 6 syntax

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
```

Comment: I searched for `of` but seems there isn't such module in the program to change!